# Padding, margin в Em

Tags: css

Необходимо для заголовка задать отступы в **em**.  Относительно чего будет высчитываться margin? Относительно размера шрифта заголовка? Или его родителя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Относительно размера шрифта заголовка, размер шрифта родителя не влияет. В примере одинаковые отступы и внутренние поля в **em**, но разные в пикселях из-за размера шрифта.

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.block--big {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.block--small {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="block block--small">text</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="block block--big">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Относительно размера шрифта **родительского** элемента.

```
.parent {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.child {
    margin: 2em; /* = 32px */
}
```

Если есть необходимость считать от постоянного размера шрифта корневого элемента, а не от родительского, то используйте `rem`.

```
html {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.any-element {
    margin: 2rem; /* = 36px */
}
```

Отличнейшим наглядным образом разница между ними двумя представлена [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units#%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-rem-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-px-%D0%B8-em).

Comment: всё-таки относительно шрифта заголовка. В Вашем примере из-за отсутствия заданного размера шрифта у *child* он наследуется от родителя. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/8wtx1yj8/2/)

Comment: @A.Gr ссылка битая. О каких заголовках вообще идет речь, а то что-то я теряюсь (давно уже не занимался версткой)

Comment: Ссылку поправил. В Вашем примере *child* в моем *заголовок*.

Comment: @A.Gr А, вот оно что. Только теперь я, кажется, понял суть вопроса. Вы спрашиваете следующее: если .child имеет font-size, то margin в em будет браться от этого font-size, а не от родительского, так?

Comment: да, именно это  спрашивалось

Comment: @A.Gr видимо и ответ я дал неверный, потому что суть вопроса понял уже после того, как дал ответ. Ну, в принципе, это не помешало вам самостоятельно проанализировать поведение и сделать выводы :)

Comment: @A.Gr Но вам еще стоит учесть и то, что размер заголовка, все-таки, лучше указывать в `rem`. Соответственно, если `em` `margin`'а будет браться от `rem` `font-size`'а, то он будет браться от `font-size`'а корневого элемента. Как-то так.

Comment: @smellyshovel как раз поэтому для заголовков (и других элементов с относительными отступами) лучше не задавать размеры в `rem`.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko как раз-таки поэтому лучше 1) не указывать отступы в `em` и `rem` 2) указывать в `em` и `rem` размер текста

Comment: я может неправ, но вот смотрите, у меня есть какая-нибудь отформатированная статья с рядом заголовков разных уровней и параграфов. как вы порекомендуете, указывать все `padding` и `margin` в пикселях? при адаптации к мелкому экрану придется переопределять вообще всё при таком подходе, а если отступы заданы в отн. единицах, то достаточно переопределить только размер шрифта.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko тут вы правы. Скорее всего от случая к случаю нужно подходить. Но тогда в margin и padding лучше использовать только rem, ибо представьте, сколько будет путаницы, если размер отступов еще и от вложенности зависеть будет (конечно, если мы не пытаемся специально добиться такого поведения).